# Is comparing the receiver email a critical part of the Paypal IPN script?

Tags: paypal

In the standard Paypal IPN PHP script, there is this line to evaluate the success of a payment:

```
if ($_POST["payment_status"] == "Completed" && $_POST["receiver_email"] == $email)
```

The purpose of evaluating payment status is obvious. But the second part of the comparison doesn't seem to add much value as far as I can tell.

The `$email` value is, as far as I understand it, simply the place you want to have errors and successful payment confirmation emails sent to. The `receiver_email` is just the email attached to merchant account on Paypal.

It seems to me that these might not be the same thing. Especially it's been tripping me up while testing with the Paypal sandbox because the merchant email address was partly auto-generated when I set up the account, and so it's not a place I can receive emails at anyway.

So, since both email addresses might be different, my initial thought is that this comparison is not so important. But maybe there's an important security consideration I'm missing.

Is this comparison critical?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a critical check in most situations because a malicious user may make a payment to his own PayPal address if you are sending the IPN in a post request (button).

Since you have 2 paypal accounts it is easier to replace

```
$_POST["receiver_email"] == $email
```

with

```
in_array($_POST["receiver_email"], array("myemail1", "myemail2"))
```

Personally I would not skip receiver checking even if your IPN url is well hidden and configured in your account. My simple approach will keep you safe from malicious requests.

Comment: Can I ask you that if checking the "business" variable is enough? It seems it is the same as the receiver email